# Submiting one form to two different URLs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cross-domain

**Hello, Folks!!**

I am not very experience. I would really appreciate some help as follows:

**Goal:** Run 2 actions associated with 1 submit, just have to add URLs and they will pull out all the necessary info they need from the form.

**Constraints:** No access to Database, No Ajax and No PHP.

**Problem:** Nothing happens even when I use `<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="OnBtn1(); OnBtn2();">`

I also tried these with no luck:

1. [Two onClick actions one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544520/two-onclick-actions-one-button)
2. [Submit single form to two actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590549/submiting-one-form-to-two-different-urls-without-ajax)

**HTML Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postToUrl () {
        document.Form1.action = "https://dB2.com/cgi-bin/b.cgi?"
        document.Form1.submit();
    }
    </script>
    <form id=" Form1" method="POST" action="https://dB1.com/cgi-bin/a.cgi?" onsubmit="postToUrl();">
        <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1">
        <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2">
        <input type="button" value="submit" name="sdb">
    </form>
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you want ajax? I don't think this problem can be solved otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use ajax, to send the form twice on the submit event.

Maybe you can try to add a hidden form with mirrored values but different `action` url. This way, when you submit the form it submit the hidden one too.